# stretching and a transparent background image in qt

Tags: image, qt, qt4, transparency, stretch

The picture in png format with a resolution of 48x48 with white background. I need to get it stretched to the size of 16x16 and a white background was transparent. To display the image I am using the code:

```
QWidget* Icon;
QPixmap ico1(":/icons/ico1.png");
QPalette pal;
    pal.setBrush(Icon->backgroundRole(), QBrush(ico1));
    Icon->setPalette(pal);
Icon->resize(16,16);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking, "How can I resize my 48x48 image to a 16x16 one, while preserving the background transparency?" ?

Comment: 1) How to load image and how to stretch it or reduce (zoom in / zoom out)
2) How to make white background transparent? that the program did not display the background image.

Answer (score 0):

for transparency use setWindowOpacity